# AJAX works in localhost but doesnt work in live web

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have searched a lot (especially on stackoverflow) but no one works on me. On localhost, the codes are simpler than on live web. On live web, i use functions (PHP). The AJAX codes are similar. It works on localhost but doesnt on live web. The code below is used for `<select>`

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").change(function(){
        var type_id=$(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', //method
            url: 'subtype.php', //action
            data: 'type_id='+type_id,
            success: function(response){
                $("#subtype").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

While in subtype.php, the receiver of AJAX is `$type_id=$_POST['type_id'];`

I've tried `console.log` but there's no error, it shows the id when I put `console.log(type_id)` (that makes me sure that my codes are correct)

Any suggest for me where I should fix?

Comment: Any error you are getting on live server?

Comment: if it not worked that means you have some error which much be addressed into browser  developer console.

Comment: You need to mention full url. eg: http://example.com/subtype.php

Comment: No error messages. I put `<option value="">Choose</option>` (in #subtype), but after I changed the `#type`, the `Choose` is gone

Comment: @Tiara  check your browser console and network tab. error will be stated there

Comment: What is the difference between the live and local server. Does the local run on windows and the live on linux? Does there is a htaccess file that can redirect the call to subtype.php?

Comment: Open your network inspector & see where it tries to send the request to.

Comment: Can you post the Error in live-modus?

Comment: I've used `console.log` and it passes the id. I also put `error: console.log("error")` on AJAX and it shows `error` in the console.. wut should I check first?

Comment: no error messages on browser console